# LaTeX3: \clist_gpop has extra pop in tabularx

Tags: tabularx, expl3, latex3

I asked about `\clist_gpop` and tabular yesterday: [LaTeX3: token list from clist_pop can't display in tabular 2nd column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412884/111676)

It's fixed. But when I change to use `tabularx`, it look like has extra pop, and it's affect by table alignment.

This is MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}
    \clist_new:N \g_sppmg_my_cl
    \clist_gset:Nn \g_sppmg_my_cl {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|}
% --------------------------------
        \clist_gpop:NN \g_sppmg_my_cl \l_tmpa_tl
        \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl 
        ``\g_tmpa_tl'' \\ 
% --------------------------------
    \end{tabularx}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

1. In this code, the output is `b` (Should be `a`)
2. If the block between two `% ----` use twice, it will output `c` and `d` two rows.
3. If change table alignment from `c` to `X` (with 2 block / 2 rows), output is `e` and `f`

Why ?

Note, I search `tabularx` and `expl3`, then I find [expl3 code with tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164738/111676) , but I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Use `\clist_pop:NN` instead, but I don't understand what you want to achieve here. If I remember correctly, `tabularx` is setting up a box first with its content, measuring the width, then recalculating

Comment: `tabularx` processes its contents twice. See [`tabularx` processes its body multiple times; how do I know which cycle I am in?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227142/5764)

Comment: @Werner usually it's more than twice, it can be variable number depending how many `\multicolumn` you have and how many iterations it takes to find good width.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that `\clist_gpop:NN` is wrong here, since `tabularx` is set in a box first, then the width of the non - X columns is determined, using the value to calculate potential `X` columns in, then the box is typeset after possible multiple further calculation steps.

Now the first 'usage' (the calculation stage here) pops 'a' from the given list there, leaving `b` as 'first' element, which is then displayed in the typeset stage with `\tl_use:N \g_tmpa_tl` after the actual 2nd pop operation. If more calculation steps occur, even more items from the `\clist` are popped (here, the `tabularx` table is processed only twice, so `b` remains)

This will happen with `\clist_pop:NN` too, but it does no harm then, since this occurs in a group (i.e. the table cell)

In total, it might be frowned on that mixing `expl3` code and a LaTeX2e environment is awkward....

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}
    \clist_new:N \g_sppmg_my_cl
    \clist_gset:Nn \g_sppmg_my_cl {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|}
% --------------------------------
        \clist_pop:NN \g_sppmg_my_cl \l_tmpa_tl
        \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl%
        ``\tl_use:N \g_tmpa_tl'' \\ 
% --------------------------------
    \end{tabularx}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so maybe change to other not pop method is the only way ? I use `\tl_set_eq` because in real case, I need use loop and put popped string to other table cell, that must be globally. (full code in my [yesterday post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412884/111676) ). Oh, I know mix `expl3` code with `LaTeX2e` maybe bad, but ... If you need program something like table, do we have another choice ?

Comment: @sppmg yes, we have. You could hide your l3 code in a macro which is in LaTeX2e syntax (reasonable). Or (less serious) use `pgf`, or `pythontex`, or `luatex`...

Comment: @Skillmon: I will change later on about the LaTeX2e wrapper

Comment: @Skillmon: Yes, that's clear after his/her comment

Comment: @Skillmon: Thanks. I'll try hide `expl3` code to macro , but not sure it can  apply to all case. `LuaTeX` maybe not good for me, because I remember it has (very) little problem for Chinese display(I need it).`pgf`, don't know it can program. `pythontex` first time know it. XD

Comment: @sppmg `pgf` has programming features, but is no match to `l3`, imho, in programming (but drawing with Ti*k*Z is great).

Answer (score 2):

This is roughly how I'd do this. Set the list in your first cell to solve the
multiple gpop problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_sppmg_my_cl
\newcommand\SetMyList[1]{
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_sppmg_my_cl { #1 }
}
\newcommand\PopMyList[1]{
  \clist_gpop:NN \g_sppmg_my_cl \l_tmpa_tl
  \cs_gset_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_tl
  %or \xdef#1{ \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|}
      \SetMyList{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}% Set the list in the first cell of tabularx
      \PopMyList{\MyTMP}%
      \MyTMP\\
      \PopMyList{\MyTMP}%
      \MyTMP\\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's hiding method right ? So `tabularx` only see the `\MyTMP` content.

Comment: Yes, I wrote a wrapper around the `\clist_gset:Nn` function and around the `\clist_gpop:NN` function. If you don't have fancy `l3` macros, `\newcommand` might be enough, else you should perhaps use `xparse` for this purpose. It also solves your problem of multiple evaluation `tabularx` does by redefining the list on each evaluation.

Comment: Oh, Is `\tl_use:N` necessary ?  Can we just use variable (`\l_tmpa_tl`) ?

Comment: No, it is not necessary. But I'd use `\cs_gset_eq:NN` or `\tl_gset_eq:NN` and not the `\xdef` approach.

Comment: Your code give me a idea . Now I move `gpop` to `tabularx` outside and save popped string and table format (`&` and `\\ ` ) to `\g_sppmg_tableContent_tl` by `\tl_gput_right:Nx`. After all done,  only put \g_sppmg_tableContent_tl` in the `tabularx`. For define macros, because every table's format may different, so I am not sure write only one usage macro is good.(But it's still has independent advantage.)

Comment: @sppmg I don't know your usage and for what you're coding this. But building the content of `tabularx` outside of it is a good idea if feasible. Note however, that this would have been possible without `l3` (just LaTeX) in a simple manner, too.